# JSON query to extract id based on name

Tags: json, jmeter

I am using a JMeter JSON extractor to try and extract an id value based on the name but it's not returning anything.

Query string I'm using is as below:

```
[?(@.name == 'Testing1')].id
```

JSON as below:

```
    {
   "data":[
      {
         "relationships":{
            "administrator_users":{
               "data":[
                  {
                     "id":"1accoun393\/customer-portal-user",
                     "type":"users"
                  }
               ]
            },
            "default_sort":{
               "data":{
                  "id":"demographics.full_name",
                  "type":"columns"
               },
               "meta":{
                  "order":"ascending"
               }
            },
            "meta":{
               "starred":false
            },
            "attributes":{
               "name":"Testing1",
               "description":"Description 1"
            },
            "id":"664f4513-5e09-49da-b045-4bd070cd8394",
            "type":"list_definitions"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

So the question is what is the correct query string?

Comment: And what's your question about this?

Comment: what's the query string that will return an ID based on name

Answer (score 0):

Let try with

```
$..relationships.[?(@.attributes[?(@.name == 'Testing1')])].id
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, didn't get a match.

Comment: You can't get a match because of your json code is not correct format.